# Unable to fetch Friendlist Birthday Facebook 3.0 android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

i am getting a null when i try to fetch my friend's birthday . this is where i set the permissions

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view
            .findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setFragment(this);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_likes",
            "friends_birthday", "friends_about_me"));

    return view;
    // return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

and this is how i am trying to fetch birthdays

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
        Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");

        Request.executeMyFriendsRequestAsync(session,
                new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users,
                            Response response) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        // Log.i("Response JSON", response.toString());
                        names = new String[users.size()];
                        id = new String[users.size()];
                        for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
                            names[i] = users.get(i).getBirthday();

                            //id[i] = users.get(i).ge();
                            Log.i("Birthday chakk te  bai ", "Birthday"
                                    + names[i]);
                        }
                    }

                });
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}
```

Please see why i am geeting null . Every thing is fine with keyhash as i tested it for friends name .

App is only in the sandbox mode.

Comment: Are you getting the other details? Can you show what are you getting  with `users.get(i).toString()`

Comment: @Shadowfax   yes i am geting other details . when i do  a `users.get(i).toString()` :`BirthdayGraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphUser, state={"id":"100002644036920","name":"Arsh Preet"}}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

Your callback, where you'll get friends and birthday info(if authenticated):

```
Session.StatusCallback statusCallback =  new Session.StatusCallback() 
{
    // callback when session changes state
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
    {
       if (session.isOpened()) 
       {
           getFriendDetails();
       }
    }
};
```

Then, open the session and set the permissions:

```
Session session = new Session(this);
session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
                       .setCallback(statusCallback)
                       .setPermissions(Arrays.asList("friends_birthday")));
```

As a last step, get the friends birthday and other details:

```
private void getFriendDetails() 
{
     Request myFriendsRequest = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), 
            new Request.GraphUserListCallback() 
     {
         @Override
         public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) 
         {
                 if (response.getError() == null) 
                 {
                    // Print response
                 }
         }
    });

    Bundle requestParams = myFriendsRequest.getParameters();
    requestParams.putString("fields", "name,birthday");
    myFriendsRequest.setParameters(requestParams);
    myFriendsRequest.executeAsync();
}
```

Comment: Let me know if it's not working, and pls accept the accept if worked! cheers!

Comment: @Shadofax  it might sound a bit silly but where do i need to put `private void makeFriendsRequest() ` and why do we actually need it . Arn't we fetching friends details in  `getFriendDetails();`

Comment: My bad, I mismatched the function name.

Comment: goes into strict mode . No response when i try to print it in `getFriendsDetails()`  No force closings though .

Comment: The code is working. Did you debug the code- where exactly the problem is